# WPF rapid CollectionChanged events blocking UI. Where & How to implement delayed update of CustomControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a somewhat complex CustomControl that, while optimized and threaded, still takes a nontrivial amount of time to update the UI after the bound collection changes.

I have this control bound to a DataGrid's SelectedItems collection.

Inherently the SelectedItems collection fires a CollectionChanged event for every individual item in the collection.

So, for example, the user drags the mouse to select 10 items which causes 10 CollectionChanged events to be fired in rapid succession.

This, in turn, causes my control to update 10 times in a row, which causes the UI to block.

To be clear, my control does do all of it's processing in a background thread, and is optimized to do the minimum amount of work on the UI thread.

What is the correct way (or some options) to 'delay' the update of a control, so that rapid CollectionChanged events (or even databinding changes) cause the minimum number of updates?

Thank you kindly for your advice.

Comment: How are you kicking off your background process? Can you show your code?

Comment: A possible approach?  Don't rely on the DataGrid directly for the SelectedItems.  Provide a checkbox column in the DataGrid and manage the collection directly.  I know this is shaky - it is just a thought.

Comment: @Rachel I am using a `Task` to run the background process (though this is quite fast). The actual slowness comes from the rendering of a Grouped ItemsControl. But again, I am 'okay' with the relative rendering speed of the control itself, the issue only stems from the multiple rapid calls.

Comment: Thanks @BalamBalam I was considering this, but the content of the DataGrid is also data-bound and can be any Type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are handling `CollectionChanged` event of the `SelectedItems` of `DataGrid` then there is no escape sadly. :(

Although you can do one thing, dont update your custom control directly by subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `DataGrid`, use an intermediate publisher-subscriber queue pair which is `DispatcherTimer` based. The timer will publish its entries every 500 milliseocnds (slow for machine but seemingly fast for a user) then publish a single event every 500 milliseconds with all collection changed events together in those 500 milliseocnds (all e.NewItems and e.OldItems collected together).

The publisher timer will ONLY start ticking if it finds at least one collection changed entry which is yet not published.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is the solution that I already had implemented, but it feels a bit unclean...

Answer (score 0):

Binding async may help.  That way the rest of the UI is processed first.

```
    Text="{Binding Path=MyGabeLib.Search.SelectedDoc.DocTextDownloadFirstPage,
           IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=Waiting_For_Server, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Also for expensive calculations I typically save the input and result and if the input does not change then I return the prior result as often the UI will sometimes make multiple calls to the get.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but it is not the getting of data that takes a longer time, but the UI rendering itself...

Comment: I think it does also delays rendering of the controls content.   Understand it does not do what you need as slow rendering is slow rendering and doing it last does not really help you.